# Komito Analytics and Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor, komito-analytics

I have used Komito Analytics before on Wordpress sites that run on WPBakery and so far they have worked with no problems at all.
We recently started using Elementor.
Would Komito Analytics work with that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Komito Analytics works fine with Elementor.
Essentially, Komito Analytics works with most WordPress page builders.